# Determining largest variable in python

Tags: python

I looked up similar questions, but most weren't in Python or were asking something a little different.

I have 5 variables, each with a value. How do I determine which variable is the largest?

I've been using five loops of something like
   if (varA > varB and varA > varC and varA > varD and varA > varE)
      varA is the largest

I think this is an obtuse way of doing it, however, and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: how about using the max function?

Comment: You should begin by some tutorials on coding, why not in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an addition to @SBillion. It seems like the asker is a python padawan, so below I show how to use `max` function with a list of ints.

```
>>> args = [1, 2, 3, 8, 19, 23, 80, 5]
>>> max_val = max(*args)
>>> print(max_val)
80
```

Comment: `max` also takes iterables, young padawan. `max(args)` where args is a list of integers works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
max(1,2,3,8,19,23,80,5)
```

It will return 80